# PyQGIS: "for" loop with nested "if ..elif ..." condition

Tags: python, pyqgis, qgis-2

I want to update an existing field according to another, it means the equivalent of a `CASE WHEN .... THEN ..... ELSE .... END` in SQL , but I want to know how to write this same update in Python for QGIS:

I wrote the following code:

---

```
#TEST : mettre à jour un champ existant avec boucle
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from qgis.core import *
vl = iface.activeLayer()
vl.startEditing()

#step 1
vl.updateFields()
idx = vl.dataProvider().fieldNameIndex( 'ETIQUETTE' )
adduc = vl.dataProvider().fieldNameIndex( 'MODE_ADDUC' )

#step 2
for f in vl.getFeatures():
    if f[adduc] == 'AERIEN':
        f[idx] = 'CIEL'
    elif f[adduc] == 'FACADE':
        f[idx] = 'MUR'
    elif f[adduc] == 'SOUTERRAIN':
        f[idx] = 'TERRE'
    else:
        f[idx] = 'RIEN'
    vl.updateFeature( f ) 

vl.commitChanges()
```

---

but but I got a Python error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 2, in <module>
KeyError: '-1'
```

Can you help me, please ?

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE! Have you tried `f['ETIQUETTE']` or `f.attribute(idx)`? Not sure whether the form `f[...]` acccepts integers or not. And is 'ETIQUETTE' the true attribute name? `KeyError: '-1'` looks like the attribute name is not existing to me.

Comment: As a first troubleshooting step, print f to determine what kind of data you're getting back. Also print adduc. Note that indexes in Python start at 0.

Answer (score 5):

I think  Jochen Schwarze is onto the problem.   The fields need to be in quotes like this:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
print(layer)
all_features = layer.getFeatures()
layer.startEditing()
for feature in all_features:
    if feature['NUMBER'] == '1337':
        att = feature.attributes()
        print(att)
    else:
        print(feature['CODE'])
    if feature['NUMBER'] == '1345':
        print(feature['NUMBER'])
        feature.setAttributes(att)
        layer.updateFeature(feature)
        att = feature.attributes()
        print(att)
```