# Add multiple fields to a shapefile based on multiple expressions

Tags: pyqgis, field-calculator, attribute-table

I would like to optimize the creation of several fields within a very large shapefile in QGIS based on multiple expressions (see below).

I've done it manually without any problem in QGIS with the field calculator but the treatment time is far too long ! I was wondering if Python could significantly speed up the process and if someone could give me a hint on how to do that ?

Here are some samples of my expressions:

- Creation of column "CODE_CONCA":

```
CONCAT("CODE_GROUP", "CODE_CULTU")
```

- Creation of column "LIBELLE":

```
CASE
WHEN  "CODE_GROUP" IS  '1' THEN 'Blé tendre'
WHEN  "CODE_GROUP" IS  '2' THEN 'Maïs grain et ensillage'
WHEN  "CODE_GROUP" IS  '3' THEN 'Orge'
END
```

- Creation of column "NOM_BIS":

```
CASE

WHEN  "LIBELLE" IS   'Autres céréales'  AND  "CODE_CONCA" NOT IN ('4TTH','4BDH') THEN 'Autres céréales (orge, millet, épeautre, sarrazin, seigle, sorho,avoine etc.)'

WHEN  "LIBELLE" IS   'Autres céréales'  AND  "CODE_CONCA" IN ('16DTY' , '16FAG' , '16GFP',  '16PP6' ) THEN 'Fourrage'

END
```

- Creation of column "CATEGORIE":

```
WHEN "NOM_BIS" IN ('Fourrage', 'Soja',  'Légumineuses / protéagineux' ) 
THEN 'Cultivé (LEG)'

WHEN "NOM_BIS" IN ( 'Autres' , 'Prairies temporaires ou permanentes' , 'Fruits à coque' ) 
THEN 'Enherbé'

END
```

- Creation of column "AZOTE":

```
CASE 

WHEN  "CATEGORIE" IS  'Cultivé'  THEN 3
WHEN  "CATEGORIE" IS  'Cultivé (LEG)'  THEN 1
WHEN  "CATEGORIE" IS  'Enherbé'  THEN 0
END
```

- Creation of column "Phyto":

```
CASE

WHEN   "NOM_BIS"  IS  'Triticale d hiver'  THEN 1.8
WHEN   "NOM_BIS"  IS  'Blé'  THEN 3.1

END
```

- Creation of column "Azote_year1":

```
"AZOTE" * "surf_ha"
```

- Creation of column "Phyto_year1":

```
"IFT" * "surf_ha"
```

***EDIT:***

Ok so I tried to create a code (see below) following the examples in the two links provided by @Taras in the comments and I came up with that script that is (obvisouly) wrong. I have lookep up into the PyQGIS developer cookbook and google in order to find the right expression for "in" and "not in" but without success !  Am I still far to the right method or am I getting close ? :D

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Thu May 14 10:49:33 2020

@author: Romain
"""

from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QVariant


#Step 1:

v1= QgsVectorLayer("E:/Stage/Modele_SIG/Etape_3/Données/RPG_2018_output/RPG_grille_2018.shp", "RPG_grille_2018", "ogr"))
all_features = v1.getFeatures()
v1.startEditing()

pr = v1.dataProvider()
pr.addAttributes([QgsField("CODE_CONCA", QVariant.String),
                  QgsField("LIBELLE",  QVariant.String),
                  QgsField("NOM_BIS", QVariant.String),
                  QgsField("CATEGORIE", QVariant.Double),
                  QgsField("AZOTE", QVariant.Int),
                  QgsField("Phyto", QVariant.Double),
                  QgsField("Azote_year1", QVariant.Double),
                  QgsField("Phyto_year1", QVariant.Double)]

v1.updateFields()


#Step 2:

#column "LIBELLE"
with edit(v1):
    for f in all_features():
    if f['CODE_GROUP'] == '1':
        f['LIBELLE'] = 'Blé tendre'
    elif f['CODE_GROUP'] == '2':
        f['LIBELLE'] = 'Maïs grain et ensillage'
    elif f['CODE_GROUP'] == '3':
        f['LIBELLE'] = 'Orge'
        v1.updateFeature(f)

#column "NOM_BIS"
with edit(v1):
    for f in all_features():
    if f['LIBELLE'] == 'Autres céréales' AND f['CODE_CONCA'] not in f['4TTH', '4BDH']:
        f['NOM_BIS'] = 'Autres céréales (orge, millet, épeautre, sarrazin, seigle, sorho,avoine etc.)'
    elif f['LIBELLE'] == 'Autres céréales' AND f['CODE_CONCA'] in f['16DTY' , '16FAG' , '16GFP',  '16PP6']:
        f['NOM_BIS'] = 'Autres céréales (orge, millet, épeautre, sarrazin, seigle, sorho,avoine etc.)'
        v1.updateFeature(f)

#column "CATEGORIE"
with edit(v1):
    for f in all_features():
    if:f['NOM_BIS'] not in f['Fourrage', 'Soja',  'Légumineuses / protéagineux']:
        f['CATEGORIE'] = 'Cultivé (LEG)'
    elif:f['NOM_BIS'] not in f['Autres' , 'Prairies temporaires ou permanentes' , 'Fruits à coque' ]:
        f['CATEGORIE'] = 'Enherbé'
        v1.updateFeature(f)

#column "AZOTE"
with edit(v1):
    for f in all_features():
    if f['CATEGORIE'] == 'Cultivé':
        f['AZOTE'] = '3'
    elif f['CATEGORIE'] == 'Cultivé (LEG)':
        f['AZOTE'] = '1'
    elif f['CODE_GROUP'] == 'Enherbé':
        f['AZOTE'] = '0'
        v1.updateFeature(f)        

#column "Phyto"
with edit(v1):
    for f in all_features():
    if f['NOM_BIS'] == 'Blé tendre':
        f['Phyto'] = '1.8'
    elif f['NOM_BIS'] == 'Maïs grain et ensillage':
        f['Phyto'] = '2.6'
        v1.updateFeature(f)

#column "Azote_year1"
with edit(v1):
    for f in all_features():
    f['Azote_year1'] = ['AZOTE*Surf_ha']
        v1.updateFeature(f)

#column "Azote_year1"
with edit(v1):
    for f in all_features():
    f['Phyto_year1'] =['Phyto*Surf_ha']
        v1.updateFeature(f)        


#Step 3:
layer.commitChanges()

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(v1)
```

Many thanks in advance !

Comment: Can you also provide examples of what you tried using python?

Comment: Have you already tried something with Python? For instance start with exploring this tutorial [PyQGIS 101: Using expressions to compute new field values](https://anitagraser.com/pyqgis-101-introduction-to-qgis-python-programming-for-non-programmers/pyqgis-101-using-expressions-to-compute-new-field-values/), therefore you will be able you to create required fields and calculate new values. Afterwards you can try this thread [PyQGIS: “for” loop with nested “if ..elif …” condition](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/313499/pyqgis-for-loop-with-nested-if-elif-condition) to embed new values.

Comment: @Taras: I was looking for such topic ! I'm gonna try based on your link and I would come back later if I'm still facing some issues ! Thanks ! :)

Comment: yes, that would be appreciated. You are welcome

Comment: by the way, is your very large shapefile stored in a database or simply as a pure  `.shp`?

Comment: Unfortunately it's a pure shapefile !

Comment: I edited my question in order to add my attempt ! :)

Comment: Are you getting an error or what?

Comment: Sorry for my late reply I was trying to debug the script myself but unfortunately I've failed ! :( I get this message error:
`Traceback (most recent call last):File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.4/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\script\ScriptEditorDialog.py", line 227, in runAlgorithmexec(self.editor.text(), d)File "<string>", line 30v1.updateQgsField()^SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With some help: [here](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.2/core/Feature/QgsFeature.html) and [here](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/index.html) and thanks to a friend, I've found a solution ! Here it goes:

```
import os
from PyQt5.QtCore import QVariant
from qgis.core import QgsVectorLayer,QgsField,QgsProject



#Etape 1: édition de mon shapefile avec ajout des colonnes à remplir selon expression de l'étape 2

v1= QgsVectorLayer("E:/Stage/Modele_SIG/Etape_3/Données/RPG_2017_output/RPG_grille_2017.shp", "RPG_grille_2017", "ogr")
all_features = v1.getFeatures()
v1.startEditing()

pr = v1.dataProvider()
pr.addAttributes([QgsField("CODE_CONCA", QVariant.String),
                  QgsField("LIBELLE",  QVariant.String),
                  QgsField("NOM_BIS", QVariant.String),
                  QgsField("CATEGORIE", QVariant.Double),
                  QgsField("AZOTE", QVariant.Int),
                  QgsField("Phyto", QVariant.Double),
                  QgsField("Azote_year1", QVariant.Double),
                  QgsField("Phyto_year1", QVariant.Double)])

v1.updateFields()

#Etape 2: calcul des nouvelles colonnes:

#column "LIBELLE"

for f in all_features:
    if f.attribute('CODE_GROUP') == '1':
        f.setAttribute(f.fields().indexOf('LIBELLE'),'Blé tendre')
    elif f.attribute('CODE_GROUP') == '2':
        f.setAttribute(f.fields().indexOf('LIBELLE'),'Maïs grain et ensillage')
    elif f.attribute('CODE_GROUP') == '3':
        f.setAttribute(f.fields().indexOf('LIBELLE'),'Orge')
    v1.updateFeature(f)

#column "NOM_BIS"
for f in all_features:
    if f.attribute('LIBELLE') == 'Autres céréales' and f.attribute('CODE_CONCA') not in ['4TTH', '4BDH']:
        f.setAttribute(f.fields().indexOf('NOM_BIS'), 'Autres céréales (orge, millet, épeautre, sarrazin, seigle, sorho,avoine etc.)')
    elif f.attribute('LIBELLE') == 'Autres céréales' and f.attribute('CODE_CONCA') in ['16DTY' , '16FAG' , '16GFP',  '16PP6']:
        f.setAttribute(f.fields().indexOf('NOM_BIS'),'Autres céréales (orge, millet, épeautre, sarrazin, seigle, sorho,avoine etc.)')
    v1.updateFeature(f)

#column "CATEGORIE"
for f in all_features:
    if f.attribute('NOM_BIS') not in ['Fourrage', 'Soja',  'Légumineuses / protéagineux']:
        f.setAttribute(f.fields().indexOf('CATEGORIE'),'Cultivé (LEG)') 
    elif f.attribute('NOM_BIS') not in ['Autres' , 'Prairies temporaires ou permanentes' , 'Fruits à coque' ]:
        f.setAttribute(f.fields().indexOf('CATEGORIE'),'Enherbé')
    v1.updateFeature(f)

#column "AZOTE"
for f in all_features:
    if f.attribute('CATEGORIE') == 'Cultivé':
        f.setAttribute(f.fields().indexOf('AZOTE'),'3')
    elif f.attribute('CATEGORIE') == 'Cultivé (LEG)':
        f.setAttribute(f.fields().indexOf('AZOTE'),'1')
    elif f.attribute('CODE_GROUP') == 'Enherbé':
        f.setAttribute(f.fields().indexOf('AZOTE'),'0')
    v1.updateFeature(f)        

#column "Phyto"
for f in all_features:
    if f.attribute('NOM_BIS') == 'Blé tendre':
        f.setAttribute(f.fields().indexOf('Phyto'),'1.8')
    elif f.attribute('NOM_BIS') == 'Maïs grain et ensillage':
        f.setAttribute(f.fields().indexOf('Phyto'),'2.6')
    v1.updateFeature(f)

#column "Azote_year1"
for f in all_features:
    azoteyear = f.attribute('AZOTE')*f.attribute('SurfHa')
    f.setAttribute(f.fields().indexOf('Azote_year1'),azoteyear)
    v1.updateFeature(f)

#column "Azote_year1"
for f in all_features:
    phytoyea1 = f.attribute('Phyto')*f.attribute('SurfHa')
    f.setAttreibute(f.fields().indexOf('Phyto_year1'), phytoyea1)
    v1.updateFeature(f)        


#Etape 3: Enregistrement des modifications et ajout au projet:
v1.commitChanges()

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(v1)
```